# Is it possible to create a windows login in angular using AWS Cognito?

Tags: angular, angularjs, amazon-web-services, window, amazon-cognito

My main question is the header.
I already did some research and it seems that it works but I can't find a good tutorial or explanation. Would be helpful if you coud help me with this, thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Do you mean like into the Windows O/S or leveraging something like Active Directory to log into something else?

Answer (score 0):

FRom your question, looks like you want to write a custom login that authenicates users with Cognito (not  Active Directory or other solutions). You can create a custom login using Angular and that uses Cognito to login.

We have a very similiar use case with the difference being the client is written in **React**. However, you can see how a custom login lets users authenicate with Cognito:

[image]

Once the user enters their user name and password, they are authenitcated.

Here is a link to similiar example. As stated in this Readme:

"User authentication is handled using Amazon Cognito. A user pool is provisioned for the app, and the PAM_EMAIL is used to create the first account. A complete user management system is outside the scope of this example. However, developers can follow the Cognito documentation to enable third-party sign-up flows to allow additional users."

See -- https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/applications/photo-asset-manager

The way to use JavaScript to authenicate is part of this example app.